# Woocommerce payment option after admin approval

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have certain requirement in woocommerce plugin. I want the new user to pay for the selected items after admin approve the order. That means user select products then add to cart and then just place order. After that admin approve the order and a payment link will be sent to the user mail account.

Please help
Thank You

Comment: I found this article but no module/plugin yet :(... http://www.woothemes.com/2012/03/case-study-warehouse-on-woo/

Comment: Also found this as an option perhaps? http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-pre-orders/

Comment: Found this plugin works great for me. http://dhrusya.com/products/wordpress-plugins/woocommerce-admin-order-approval/

Comment: found a plugin for that
https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-approval-woocommerce/
premium 
https://sevengits.com/plugin/sg-order-approval-woocommerce-pro/